# Track conversions with Facebook Pixel, from Paypal-IPN

Tags: php, facebook, paypal, google-analytics, paypal-ipn

With a Paypal simple "Buy button" on a site, the only way to be 100% sure that there is a purchase is to use the PHP [IPN script](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) after a purchase.

I can't rely on firing the `fbq('track', 'Purchase');` event when a customer visits a `example.com/successpayment` because 20%+ of the time they don't go to this page (according to my past months stats).

**How to trigger a Facebook pixel event (similar to `fbq('track', 'Purchase');`) from a Paypal-IPN PHP script?** by passing a specific clientId? (in the same way than [GoogleAnalytics's clientId in measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid))

The tricky part is that **the IP that calls this ipn.php script *is Paypal*, and not the customer's IP**. Thus Facebook cannot make a link between the FB pixel visitor and the customer.

---

The problem is the same for GoogleAnalytics, but [there is a solution](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/108349/79015): we can get the GoogleAnalytics clientId via `ga(function(tracker) { console.log(tracker.get('clientId')); });`, then pass it to Paypal, then after a purchase when Paypal calls the IPN script, we get this clientId back in the IPN PHP, ... and then when triggering a "Purchase" event with [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), we can send this clientId: the link is done between the *visitor* (as seen by GA during the website visit) and the *customer* (as seen by IPN PHP)!

Comment: If you have information to identify the user on your end, then you could send Offline Conversions, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions

Comment: That's interesting indeed @CBroe. But how to make a link between the visitor of the website (tracked by FB Pixel javascript code) and the customer who made an offline conversion? Example: let's say we have many ads, and we want to track which ad is responsible for a conversion, it is absolutely needed, when reporting an offline conversion to have a user id, to be able to link it to the original visitor. (If not, we cannot know which ad was good for conversions, which ad was bad). Do you see what I mean? Is there a user ID somewhere I can use?

Comment: You can not get a FB user id unless the user logs in to your app. You need to match them based on other information you have available in such a case: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/offline-conversions#match-keys

Comment: @CBroe: when a visitor visits the website (including FB pixel), I can send to FB a generated-by-myself-random-ID: `fbq('trackCustom', 'customId', {custom_param: '12345678ABCDEF'});`. Then, this ID can be passed to PayPal. When Paypal-IPN arrives (after payment), I could report `offline conversion associated to customId #12345678ABCDEF` to FB. Then FB could know which visitor it was, helpful to build a custom audience, and above all to know **which ad** among the many ads I made is responsible for the purchase. How is this workflow possible?